# How do I send RTSP video to a program that reads from a character device?

Tags: video, devices, streaming, camera

I have an IP-CAM that streams video over RTSP and I want to detect bar codes from it with `zbarcam` (from Ubuntu's [`zbar-tools` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/zbar-tools)).

According [`zbarcam`'s manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/zbarcam.1.html), it expects to be given a video4linux character device (default `/dev/video0`). How can I let it receive that RTSP stream instead?

---

I tried to use `mplayer`, but I can't figure out how I could use that to pipe the stream to `zbarcam`.

Comment: You might be able to implement it using the instructions from http://superuser.com/questions/411897/using-desktop-as-fake-webcam-on-linux

Comment: Great hint. Meantime I tried to create a node (mknod) but this didn't worked. I will try that ffmpeg v4l-device. Thank you. You better should use answers, then i can vote.

Comment: I wasn't actually giving a real answer, it was just a hint. I'll try to suggest an answer more properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something on these lines:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-utils gstreamer1.0-tools
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback # might not be needed
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://your_stream_url ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

Then you should be able to use zbarcam against /dev/video1 as usual.

Comment: I think this could work, but not on my rasp pi. there is a problem with that v4l2loopback, can't get it to work.

Comment: What exactly fails? I guess v4l2loopback should be cross-platform...

Comment: Is not part of my dist. so i have to compile it. won't compile because i didn't setup the infrastructure correct. I only need time, it's not a technical problem anymore. thx

Comment: It's not working on my RaspPi either. The error is given below,
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)